# Issue reading variables from a file

Tags: c++

I have a file with just one line

"P00321 A 9"

I need to bring each of these in as 3 individual variables, but it seems they aren't being read correctly with the code I have.

```
ifstream inFile;
int hours;
string accountnum;
char servicecode;

...

inFile.open("inputs.dat");
inFile >> accountnum >> servicecode >> hours;
```

If I cout these accountnum comes up blank, servicecode comes up as an underlined @ symbol, and hours is a long decimal number.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are the quotes in the file?

Comment: And did you check to see if the open was successful?

Comment: Realized the input file was named "input" not "inputs" Boy do I feel dumb haha. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: @SyntaxSyntax, please delete the post. It's not going to be useful to any body else.

Comment: always check the return codes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you keep the "inputs.dat" file in a correct format(i.e. ANSI)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `strtok` with a blank space as delimiter?
`char* strtok( char* str, const char* delim );`
Call this three times to get three individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly

- Check the file path
- Check if the program cloud open the file
- Try to run this code and check the result

**code**

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    int hours;
    std::string accountnum;
    char servicecode;  

    inFile.open("E:\\input.dat");
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        inFile >> accountnum >> servicecode >> hours;
        std::cout << accountnum << std::endl;
        std::cout << servicecode << std::endl;
        std::cout << hours << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "cant open" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**File**

`P00321 A 9`